# Preposition “under” and “above”

Tags: prepositions

Situation: Susan and Jane live in the same flat. Jane’s room is 201, on the 2nd floor, while Susan’s is 301, on the 3rd floor.

Is it correct to say “Susan’s room is **above** Jane’s and Jane’s room is **under** Susan’s?

Thank you.

Comment: Your question gives rise to questions. Are you referring to multitude of flats? Or are you referring to a duplex flat? If it is the first, you can use "same flats" instead of "same flat". It will be less ambiguous.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is - but it's not correct to say that they live in the same flat!

We British call an apartment a 'flat' when all the rooms are on the same level. It is possible to have an apartment which includes rooms on two floors of a building, but I wonder whether you mean to say that they live in the same *block of flats* (or *apartment building*).

Comment: Since it's a residential term, it's localized. Different places use different terms. In Chicago, for instance, a "2-flat" or a "3-flat" refer to types of row houses, consisting of at least two apartments, upstairs and down. But you'll get a blank look if you use the terms elsewhere.

Comment: Thank you Kate! 
 
So when it comes to ‘a block of flats’, it means there can be two or more storeys, am I right? 

And to avoid misunderstanding, should I say “Susan and Jane live in the same building”?

Comment: A block of flats (in the UK) consists of two or more storeys by definition, sometimes many more if it's a 'tower block'. It usually refers to a building designed for multiple occupation, as distinct from a large house that has been divided into flats. Yes, they live in the same building, or block of flats.